# Early withdrawal fee for compound interest CD investment

Tags: finance

Suppose you buy a CD for $1000 that earns 2.5% APR and is compounded quarterly. The CD matures in 5 years. Assume that if funds are withdrawn before the CD matures, the early withdrawal fee is 3 months' interest. What is the early withdrawal fee on this account?

1. \$1.25
2. \$3.75
3. \$3.13
4. \$6.25

Comment: Please avoid titles in full caps, also try to make your titles hint on the content of the post.

Comment: Wouldn't the amount depend on when the early withdrawal occurred? (One  of the choices gives the smallest possible value it could be.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you ignore the compounding, how much interest is collected in one year?  How much is one quarter of that?